# How to truncate number to 2 decimal places in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, formatting, decimal

How can I take some variables and output them only to two decimal places, but leave the variables themselves unchanged?

I tried

```
NumberFormat(reportData, '0,00')
```

But the numbers remained the same.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`,` is the separator for thousands and `0` stands for "pad with zero", as can be read [in the official documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_m-r_08.html). Try it like this:

```
NumberFormat(reportData, '9.99');
```

Comment: Its worth noting that this will round to two decimal places, not truncate. Use NumberFormat((Int(reportData*100)/100), '9.99'); to truncate.

Answer (score 12):

If you're in a country where the decimal separator happens to be `,` and not `.` then you should use [LSNumberFormat](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6d91.html) instead.  Either in conjuction with [SetLocale](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fa3.html), or specifying the `locale` attribute of the function.  e.g.

```
<cfoutput>#LSNumberFormat(reportData, "0.00", "Swedish")#</cfoutput>
```

OR

```
<cfscript>setLocale("Swedish");</cfscript>
<cfoutput>#LsNumberFormat(reportData, "0.00")#</cfoutput>
```

Notice that in the `mask` attribute we're still using `.` as the decimal separator.  This then gets mapped to whatever the Swedish decimal separator is (a comma).